# How to implement computeIfAbsent in order to return Object value?

Tags: java, function, collections

I have written a method that takes a name of some field and if it's an essential field, the value is calculated for the field and is put into the map for the key.

```
private final Map<String, Object> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();

private void saveValues(String name) {
    if (dataStore.isEssentialField(name)) {
        valuesMap.put(name, calculateValue(name));
    }
}
```

Now I want to achieve the following: if there is already a value associated with the `name` key or the key is not an "essential field", the method must return the existing value and not calculate anything.

I suppose it may be achieved with `computeIfAbsent` method of a `Map` interface but not sure how to implement this correctly. How should the Function be implemented in this case?

```
private Object saveValues(String name) {
    if (dataStore.isEssentialField(name)) {
        Object newValue = valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(name, -> (Function<? super String, ?>) calculateValue(name));
    }
    return ... ? // How can the existing value be returned here?
}
```

Comment: There is a hole in your requirement "if there is already a value associated with the "name" key or the key is not "essentialField", the method must return the existing value". What if the key is not essential and there is no existing value ?

Comment: `return datastore.get(name);`

Comment: @GPI probably the only option in the situation when the key is not essential and there is no existing value, is to return `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Lambda function as follows:

```
private Object saveValues(String name) {
    if (dataStore.isEssentialField(name)) {
        return valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(name, this::calculateValue);
    }
    return valuesMap.get(name);
}
```

The more classical approach would be:

```
private Object saveValues(String name) {
    Object storedValue = valuesMap.get(name);
    if (dataStore.isEssentialField(name)) {
        if (storedValue != null) {
            return storedValue;
        }
        storedValue = calculateValue(name);
        valuesMap.put(name, storedValue);
    }
    return storedValue;
}
```

Comment: could you tell what did `s` mean in your previous edit  `return valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(name, s -> calculateValue(name));` ?

Comment: That should have been `return valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(name, s -> calculateValue(s));`. Lambda are just a short way of calling code. In this scenario the compiler understands that we are dealing with an `interface` that just has a single method to be implemented (called `apply(...);`). `s -> calculateValue(s)` creates a `new Function<String, Object>` and implements the single method there is with `calculateValue(s)` where `s` is the single parameter in `apply(T t);`.

Comment: `this::calculateValue` just drives this one step further and ditches the parameter, as the compiler knows that we have one parameter coming into our implementation and one parameter which is passed to `calculateValue(...)`. In that case you can write it like I did above (although you should know that the java runtime will create an object in the background which consumes memory and costs time to allocate and garbage collect like any other object)